# ADATA 2TB external hard drive shows as No Media and 0.00GB space

Tags: mount, hard-drive, gparted

`ll -s /dev | grep sd` shows sda and sdb, sdb being the corrupted drive.

```
$ sudo mount -t auto /dev/sdb /mnt      
mount: /dev/sdb: can't read superblock
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: No such file or directory
```

Disks view:

[image: Disks view]

The drive is not recognized by GParted

`dmesg`:

```
[65721.846524] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[65721.847478] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[65723.889423] .
[65724.913413] .
...
[65822.192895] .
[65822.192897] not responding...
[65843.034144] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[65843.034149] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[65843.034151] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[65843.034156] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[65843.034157] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 0-byte physical blocks
[65849.983964] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[65856.933840] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[65856.933851] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[65856.935477] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[65857.968636] .
...
[65957.232040] .
[65957.232043] not responding...
[65978.080089] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[65978.080093] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[65978.080094] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[65991.980031] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[66032.455058] EXT4-fs (sdb): unable to read superblock
[66032.455512] EXT4-fs (sdb): unable to read superblock
[66032.456062] EXT4-fs (sdb): unable to read superblock
[66032.456461] SQUASHFS error: squashfs_read_data failed to read block 0x0
[66032.456468] squashfs: SQUASHFS error: unable to read squashfs_super_block
[66097.793285] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[66098.799233] .
...
[66198.126641] .
[66198.126645] not responding...
[66218.972974] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[66218.972981] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[66218.972985] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[66970.067911] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[66971.082123] .
...
[67070.409614] .
[67070.409617] not responding...
[67091.246320] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[67091.246334] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[67091.246339] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
```